ggcoef_model not displaying all interaction comparisons
hunger <- sample(x = 0:1, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
treat <- sample(x = c("A1","A2"), prob = c(.75, .25), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
owner <- sample(x = c("Alice","Ben"), prob = c(.5, .5), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
animal <- sample(x = c("dog","cat","cow"), prob = c(.33, .33, .33), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(animal,treat,owner,hunger))
df$hunger <- as.numeric(df$hunger)
df$animal <- as.factor(df$animal)

I have a dataframe as above and produce a glmer model (with the variable "animal" devation-coded):

contrasts(df$animal) = contr.sum(3) #setup contrast for deviation coding (1-2, 1-3. 2-3, comparisons)

testM <- glmer(hunger ~ animal + treat + animal*treat  + 
            (1 + animal + treat + animal*treat||owner), data = df,  family="binomial", glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun=1e5)))
summary(testM)

I wish to visualize this model using ggcoef_model. However, when I use
ggcoef_model(testM, include = !contains(c("owner","Residual.sd")))

It produces the following visualization

In the bottom of the graph, under the "animal * treat" header we see "cat * A2" and "cow * A2", but no "dog * A2" - why not? How can I display the "dog * A2" level as well?

Does this answer your question? ggcoef_model change labels of levels

It does not - the other thread is concerned with changing the labels of the levels - here, the problem is that not all levels (it appears to me) are shown.
Specifically, the "dog * A2" comparison is missing (regardless of how we may name the levels that are part of this interaction).

With deviation coding (also known as sum contrasts), the sum of the contrasts for each factor sums to zero. Each level is compared to the overall mean rather than a specific reference level. This means that each level's coefficient represents the deviation from the mean effect of the factor levels.
For your model, the animal factor is deviation-coded, and thus the baseline for the interaction terms will involve the reference level of animal (in your case, likely dog if dog is the first level).
You can verify the reference level using levels(df$animal).
The estimate for dog:A2 is implicitly represented in the intercept and the overall mean, hence it is not shown explicitly. However we can make use of the emmeans package which can be used to compute and visualise the estimated marginal means for each combination of factors, which includes the interaction effects. You could try something like this:
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)

contrasts(df$animal) = contr.sum(3)
testM <- glmer(hunger ~ animal + treat + animal*treat + 
            (1 + animal + treat + animal*treat || owner), data = df, family = "binomial", glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5)))

emmeans_results <- emmeans(testM, ~ animal * treat)
summary(emmeans_results)

pairwise_comparisons <- contrast(emmeans_results, method = "pairwise")
summary(pairwise_comparisons)

These can then be visualised:
plot(emmeans_results, comparisons = TRUE)


which now includes the "missing" Dog:A2 interaction

Edit to address the 2nd question in the first comment, adding a combined plot of all main effects and interactions:
library(ggplot2)
emmeans_main_effects_animal <- emmeans(testM, ~ animal)
emmeans_main_effects_treat <- emmeans(testM, ~ treat)
emmeans_interactions <- emmeans(testM, ~ animal * treat)

emm_main_animal_df <- as.data.frame(emmeans_main_effects_animal)
emm_main_treat_df <- as.data.frame(emmeans_main_effects_treat)
emm_interactions_df <- as.data.frame(emmeans_interactions)

ggplot() +
  # Main effects for animal
  geom_point(data = emm_main_animal_df, aes(x = animal, y = emmean), color = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(data = emm_main_animal_df, aes(x = animal, ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), width = 0.2, color = "blue") +
  # Main effects for treat
  geom_point(data = emm_main_treat_df, aes(x = treat, y = emmean), color = "green") +
  geom_errorbar(data = emm_main_treat_df, aes(x = treat, ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), width = 0.2, color = "green") +
  # Interaction effects
  geom_point(data = emm_interactions_df, aes(x = interaction(animal, treat), y = emmean), color = "red") +
  geom_errorbar(data = emm_interactions_df, aes(x = interaction(animal, treat), ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), width = 0.2, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Main Effects and Interaction Effects", x = "Levels", y = "Estimated Marginal Means") +
  theme_minimal()



Thank you for this reply.
(1) Can you explain the sentence "dog:A2 is implicitly represented in the intercept and the overall mean" in more detail? How is this dog:A2 captured by the intercept and overall mean in the original visualization?
(2) Also is there a way to apply this solution while also keeping all the non-interaction effects visualized in the same plot (i.e. the main effects of cat, cow, dog, etc.)

I'm out of town just now and only have my phone so I can't reply at length. Regardless, for your first question, when you look at summary(testM) note that it's not just that particular interaction (Dog:A2) that is absent; there is no estimate for the main effects of Animal3 (dog) or  treatA1, or any other the interactions involving those factor levels. Anything involving Dog (Animal3) and treatment 1 (treat1) will also be absent. This includes: Dog:treat1, Cow:treat1 and Cat:treat1. This is because they are included in the intercept....[cont]

...[cont] That's just how the model fitting procedure works. The "missing" estimates, however, can be obtained easily because of the sum-to-zero coding. So for Animal3, we have Animal1 + Animal2 + Animal3 = 0 thus it is trivial to compute Animal3. Similar logic applies to the interactions, albeit a little less trivial.  The emmeans package was written partly in order to deal with these issues. This is now becoming more of a statistics question, so of you have any further queries of this kind, I would suggest asking it over at stats.stackexchange.com ......[Cont]..

...[cont]...If you use the emmeans tag there is a good chanve that Russ Lenth (the author of the emmeans package) will reply. On the other hand if you think that it's still primarily about coding then stackoverflow also has an emmeans tag so hopefully he would reply to a new question here.

Just got home, and added code to plot all effects (main + interactions), to address your 2nd question. Hope it helps !

Thanks for accepting my answer :) I just thought it worthwhile mentioning that the random effects of your proposed model are rather complex. The model converges to a singular fit which is evidence that the random effects are overfitted. I appreciate that the data in the question are simulated, which also might be the reason for the singular fit, but if that happens with your real data (singular fit) then you will need to address that (usually by simplifying the random effects. There are a ton of questions, many of which I have answered, on this topic at stats.stackexchange.com
